# Is there any way to find gesture recognizer in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiwebview

I am trying ebook reading app. In that I want create UIActionSheet by clicking on the index page link..For that how can I identify the touch event in webView as WebView already have the inbuilt longTouch event. Is there any way to identify that longtouch event in webView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just overwrite below method to work our gerstures

```
  - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer
        *)otherGestureRecognizer
   {
        return YES;
   }

        For adding longPress add to your view



UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)];
longPress.minimumPressDuration=0.8;
longPress.delegate = self;
[self addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
[longPress release];

- (void)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gesture 
{
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesnt go into the longPress: method..and it shows the inbuilt pop up window.

Comment: i forget add delegate to longPress then it will call

Comment: can you please tel me how to hide inbuilt popup window in webview?